# Javascript elements classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'll try be specific with what I'm trying to do and what I've tried so far.

I've been tasked with building a drop down menu with 200 countries. When a country is selected it will display what payment processors are available for your selected country.

I've got something working here  ( only 3 countries ) 
http://davidstokes.com/1/payments/payments-dropdown.html
I've also added the code to JS fiddle but for some reason doesn't work, Might be external files not loading correcting.

```
`function showDivIE() {
 document.getElementById('ireland').style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById('canada').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById('uk').style.display = "none";
}
function showDivCA() {
document.getElementById('canada').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('ireland').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('uk').style.display = "none";
}
function showDivUK() {
document.getElementById('uk').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('ireland').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('canada').style.display = "none";
}'
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dave5000/0jwhwezq/

But you'll be able to see what code I have.

I want to change the document.getElementById selector to something else that lets me select multiple items. So when i need to hide country x/y/z i can enter then all in one area and not have to have multiple getElementsBy options.

Any help or suggestions would be great.

Comment: use "document.getElementsByClassName" or jquery(recommended)

Comment: I've tested document.getElementsByClassName but it's not working. I checked the DIV id's to DIV classes.. was that correct ?

Comment: @user3546063, try now the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0jwhwezq/1/. It should work.

Comment: In jsfiddle you are getting errors such as `ReferenceError: showDivCA is not defined` so I guess you aren't really calling your show functions, so it doesn't matter what you put in them.

Comment: thanks @Ionut what did i have wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a common class to each of the blocks, i.e. for Ireland replace this:

```
<div id="ireland" style="display:none;">
```

with this:

```
<div id="ireland" style="display:none;" class="countryblock">
```

Given that all the blocks have a common class, you can use the following function:

```
function showDiv(id) {
    // $(selector) is a shortcut for jQuery(selector)
    $('.countryblock').hide(); // Hides every block with a table that is not currently hidden
    $('#'+id).show(); // Shows one particular block you want to show
}
```

And call it like that:

```
showDiv('uk');
```

Comment: If you take this approach, be sure [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) is included on your page (I see it's in your JSFiddle config).

Comment: When i try this I select Ireland it displays Ireland. But when I change my selection to UK it shows Ireland and UK. If you change from one to another you shouldn't see the old selection. Only the current one.

Comment: That means you didn't add a common class to every block.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'getElementsByClassName' instead of 'getElementById'. Just add a class to each div e.g. country

document.getElementsByClassName('country')

You can then loop through each element and set the style.

Also there's getElementsByTagName if you prefer not adding a class, but then you have to filter the div with 'dropdown' class.